# Windows form this.hide() doesn't work

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a little question, because I don't understand something.

I wrote a WinForm application with two forms (Login & Dashboard)

The startup Form is the Login Form.
If the login does work, the form should switch to the dashboard form.
The login form should be hidden/disabled.

In the code, the application writes an entry, that the user logged in (Stay logged in) and don't have to enter the credentials by the next startup.

Now the issue is, that the Login form always shows up when I launch the application. Although the application passes the point this.hide().

Here is the code from the Login form, These Snippe

```
 public LOGIN()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        if (File.Exists(programpath + "config.dat"))
        {
            lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(programpath + "config.dat");
            uid = lines[0];
            pwd = lines[1];
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            NameValueCollection formParams = new NameValueCollection();
            formParams["uid"] = Encrypt.DecryptString(uid,"test");
            formParams["pwd"] = Encrypt.DecryptString(pwd, "test");
            byte[] responseByte = client.UploadValues(url, "POST", formParams);
            string result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responseByte);
            if (result == "true")
            {
                var frm = new Dashboard();
                frm.Location = this.Location;
                frm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
                frm.FormClosing += delegate { this.Show(); };
                frm.Show();
                this.Hide();
            }
        }
    }
```

Can anybody explain to me why this happens and what should I do?

Comment: There is no `this.hide();` in the code you share. You should put your logic the place where you are opening the Login Form and Open LoginForm or DashBoard form directl from there instead of opening LoginForm and then deciding.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya
I edited the code, I'm sorry

Comment: Did you try to close first login form and then show dashboard form? I mean, write down this.Hide() as first line before if (result == "true").

Comment: That's because you have you "login logic" code in the form constructor _(which is executed before the form is shown)_, therefore, when you call `.Hide()`, it doesn't have any effect (remember the form isn't shown yet). And then later on, the form gets shown normally. **Never** add any code in the form constructor **unless** it's something that needs to be done right after an instance of the form _and its controls_ are created. You can move your code to the `Form.Shown` event, or handle in a different way of your choice (Note that `Form.Load` won't work either for the same reason).

Answer (score 0):

Someone at comment answered your question but here is more explanation:

If you go to [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/order-of-events-in-windows-forms) you will find lifecycle of windows form `FORM`

So it goes like this when starting form:

- Control.HandleCreated
- Form.Load
- Form.Activated
- Form.Shown

As explanation for `Form.Shown` in documentation it is written `Occurs whenever the form is first displayed.`

So basically when you do in your code:

```
Form f1 = new Form();
```

You have created instance of your form which runs `public f1()` inside your `f1` file BUT still it is not shown so you cannot hide what isn't even shown.

When you call `f1.Show()` or `f1.ShowDialog()` it will `show` form and that is done before `Form.Shown` part is fired so inside that method yor form IS shown.

Solution for this is to go to your form and create `Form.Shown()` event (in design windows select form (not control inside it) and on the right side you have property window. In top bar in property window you can switch between properties and events. Switch to events and find `Shown` event. When you find it double click in space on the right and it will automatically create event in code for you)

Now when you have created your shown event copy your code inside it and it will work.

Answer (score -2):

I have to add the If statement in the static void main method.
In this case it does work.